# Ubuntu 16.04 freezes after login

Tags: 16.04, login-screen, freeze, crash, bug-reporting

First of all I deleted the guest session so no guest could log in but now when I start my computer the login screen shows a guest session option also. And then after I login the screen freezes but I can move the cursor. But the screen freezes for forever. I have some important  data in my laptop will I lose all the data. Pls help

My system: HP pavillion g6-1200TU with 2 GB Ram,  Intel Core i3-2330M with 2.2 ghz having 4 cores, with Intel HD graphics 3000, 500gb HDD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to turn the Unity plugin back on. The problem is this is a pain in the bottom because you've now got no graphical method to do this. So:

Try to open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

This may not work but you can try right clicking on the desktop and selecting "Open terminal here." Otherwise, you may need to change to a "hard" terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and log in.

Install compizconfig-settings-manager by running

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Then run it with this:

```
DISPLAY=:0 ccsm &
```

The first part tells the terminal which display you want it to load on (otherwise it won't have a clue).

If you switched to a TTY in step 1, switch back to the graphical server by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> sometimes).

There there should be a CompizConfig Settings Manager waiting for you.

Find the Unity plugin. Enable it. You will be asked "Ubuntu Unity Plugin requires the plugin OpenGL. Enable Ubuntu Unity Plugin / Enable OpenGL"

Everything should spring into life but if it doesn't, you might have to restart. You can do that by going back to the terminal and running sudo reboot.

Comment: I have installed compizconfig-settings-manager. Do I need to run Display :-0 ccsm &  command directly from the terminal? What command should i type to run it. And pls tell the commands which i have to type. I am new to ubuntu. Pls help

Comment: I have done it. It doesn't help

Comment: Thanks. I have fixed the problem. Actually I installed Java 8 on ubuntu 16.04 last night and did something with the path variable in /etc/environment file, so it was causing the problem. So I changed it back to what it was earlier and rebooted. And the system is running perfect now. Thanks!

Comment: Pretty neat. I'm running Ubunto 16.04 LTS in VMWare. But while your solution brings up ccsm, after reboot I still have the same problem.

Comment: I have a similar problem with the symptoms, but the terminal shortcut does nothing, and trying to switch to a tty makes the screen freeze completely. I think the noveau drivers are to blame, probably something to do with modeset, but I can't get into a terminal to change it. Can't get into grub either, it just doesn't respond to shift.

Answer (score 0):

If the screen grays out a bit and the mouse changed into an X, then there is probably/likely an X authentication problem. I had this happen to me because (after playing around a bit) I ended up with an empty (size 0) /home/carlo/.Xauthority file owned by root. Removing that file fixed the problem (if you kill Xorg it will restart and then let you login as normal).